# random hash function, compute the expected number of empty table entries

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, hashcode

I am working on hash tables.In hash tables we have wastage of space due to empty table entries. can we have any hash function that can compute expected number of empty entries.

I have seen the same question being asked in many textbooks, and there was a hint saying that we can use indicator random variables to generate a random hash function.I was not actually cleared about that concept...could any one explain them in detail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for. "hash function that can compute expected number of empty entries" -- hash  functions used to map keys to indices, not to compute any number. "many textbooks" -- what books?

Comment: "use indicator random variables" -- what is this?

Comment: u can check the same question from the following text book Its " Algorithms and data structures " by kruth mehlhorn and peter sanders. http://e-maxx.ru/bookz/files/algorithms_toolbox_mehlhorn.pdf            It's exercise 4.6 in chapter 4. any how thanks for the reply I have already got a solution for the problem.